# Show table id based on radio button selection.

Tags: javascript, jquery

Objective - user select regular, short or long then toggle between Inch and CM based on the selection made previously.
The first tier is already working so we show a different table based on selecting options regular, short or long now I just need the ability to show a table in inch or CM. please see code below. any help is welcome. thanks

```js
var tables = $('.charge-table');
$('input[name="group1"]').on('change', function() {
  tables.hide();
  $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

```css
#charge {
  display: table;
}
.charge-table {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="selection1" type="radio" name="group1" value="charge" checked>Regular
  <br/>
  <input id="selection2" type="radio" name="group1" value="charge1">Short
  <br/>
  <input id="selection3" type="radio" name="group1" value="charge2">Long
  <br/>
</div>
<br/>
<div>
  <input id="selection4" type="radio" name="group1" value="charg3">Inches
  <br/>
  <input id="selection5" type="radio" name="group1" value="charge4">CM
  <br/>

</div>


<table id="charge" class="charge-table">
  <tr>
    <td>Regular</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="charge1" class="charge-table">
  <tr>
    <td>Short</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="charge2" class="charge-table">
  <tr>
    <td>Long</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: not fully sure what your trying to achieve here could you explain in some mroe details.  " I just need the ability to show a table in inch or CM".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Separate the Inches and CM to another group.
2. Add class `.charge-row` to `<tr>`s.
3. Add `.charge3` and `.charge4` as class to different tr.
4. Add another input change listener to act the similar action.

Or

1. Change the use `chargeX` as class, and create all the combinations from length and type (So created 6 table), add class to each of them like `charge1 charge4` ...
2. When any of the group's value changed, get both value of them, eg. `value1=charge1, value2=charge4`.
3. hide all tables.
4. use `$('.' + value1 + '.' + value2).show()` to show the target table.

```js
var tables = $('.charge-table');
var rows = $('.charge-row');
$('input[name="group1"]').on('change', function() {
  tables.hide();
  $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
});
$('input[name="group2"]').on('change', function() {
  rows.hide();
  $('.' + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

```css
#charge {
  display: table;
}

.charge-row.charge3 {
  display: table-row;
}

.charge-table, .charge-row {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="selection1" type="radio" name="group1" value="charge" checked>Regular
  <br/>
  <input id="selection2" type="radio" name="group1" value="charge1">Short
  <br/>
  <input id="selection3" type="radio" name="group1" value="charge2">Long
  <br/>
</div>
<br/>
<div>
  <input id="selection4" type="radio" name="group2" value="charge3" checked>Inches
  <br/>
  <input id="selection5" type="radio" name="group2" value="charge4">CM
  <br/>

</div>


<table id="charge" class="charge-table">
  <tr class="charge3 charge-row">
    <td>Regular</td><td>Inches</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="charge4 charge-row">
    <td>Regular</td><td>CM</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="charge1" class="charge-table">
  <tr class="charge3 charge-row">
    <td>Short</td><td>Inches</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="charge4 charge-row">
    <td>Short</td><td>CM</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="charge2" class="charge-table">
  <tr class="charge3 charge-row">
    <td>Long</td><td>Inches</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="charge4 charge-row">
    <td>Long</td><td>CM</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, if you can save the data in js. I'd prefer only have 1 table, and have a function that will get value from `{regular, short, long}` and `{inches, cm}` and create formatted data, then update each td's text to the new data.

```js
var $table = $('.charge-table');

// Fake data.
var data = [['data']];

// Create 
var lMapping = {
    charge : 'Regular',
    charge1: 'Short',
    charge2: 'Long'
};
var tMapping = {
    charge3: 'Inches',
    charge4: 'CM'
};

var renderTable = function() {
    // Get value from each group
    var value1 = $('input[name="group1"]:checked').val();
    var value2 = $('input[name="group2"]:checked').val();
  
    // Put data to each td.
    data.forEach(function(rowData, i) {
        var $row = $table.find('tr').eq(i);
        rowData.forEach(function(item, j) {
            var $td = $row.find('td').eq(j);
          
            // Create formatted data from radio values.
            var str = lMapping[value1] + ' ' + tMapping[value2] + ' ' + data;
            $td.text(str);
        });
    });
};


$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', renderTable);

// Set init state.
renderTable();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input id="selection1" type="radio" name="group1" value="charge" checked /> Regular
  <br/>
      <input id="selection2" type="radio" name="group1" value="charge1"/>Short
  <br/>
      <input id="selection3" type="radio" name="group1" value="charge2" />Long
  <br/>
      <hr/>
<div/>
<div>
    <input id="selection4" type="radio" name="group2" value="charge3" checked />Inches
  <br/>
      <input id="selection5" type="radio" name="group2" value="charge4" />CM
  <br/>
</div>

<table id="charge" class="charge-table">
  <tr>
    <td>Regular</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```